# Is Thread managed by the thread pool?

Tags: c#, clr, threadpool

I know that the CLR gives each `AppDomain` `ThreadPool` time slice to work , yet i wanted to know if by creating a new thread like so `Thread t = new Thread(...);`

Is it managed by the CLR or by the `AppDomin ThreadPool` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create threads with the `Thread` class, **you** are in control. You create them as you need them, and you define whether they are [background or foreground](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx) (keeps the calling process alive), you set their [`Priority`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.priority.aspx), you start and stop them.

With [`ThreadPool`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx) or [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) (which use the `ThreadPool` behind the scenes) you let the `ThreadPool` class manage the creation of threads, and maximizes reusability of threads, which saves you the time needed to create a new thread. One thing to notice is that unlike the `Thread` default, threads created by the `ThreadPool` don't keep the calling process alive.

A huge advantage of using the `ThreadPool` is that you can have a small number of threads handle lots of tasks. Conversely, given that the pool doesn't kill threads (because it's designed for reusability), if you had a bunch of threads created by the `ThreadPool`, but later the number of items shrinks, the `ThreadPool` idles a lot, wasting resources.

Answer (score 6):

`Thread t = new Thread();` will not be managed by the `ThreadPool`.  But it is an abstraction provided by the CLR on the Operating System threads.  ThreadPool is an addtional abstraction which facilitates reusing threads and sharing thread resources.

Here is an excellent resource on threads in .NET: http://www.albahari.com/threading/

If you're using .NET 4.0 consider using TPL.

Comment: I am using .Net 4
In a job interview i said that that a Thread is not managed by the threadpool and the  Team leader said i was wrong. Now the question is do i correct him :)

Answer (score 1):

When you create new threads they are **not** managed by the thread pool.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a thread manually then you control its life time, this is independent from the Thread pool.